# Jquery conflict betwwen joomla extension

Tags: jquery

How to insert jQuery.noConflict(); to avoid conflict between Moset tree component and Autson Slideshow and where exactly?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When in Joomla!, it's better to use the API provided to incluse js and CSS files.

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('path/to/jquery.js');
$document->addScriptDeclaration('jQuery.noConflict()');
```

Comment: I know all this code but how to insert it and where and in which file?

Comment: You may insert it in your template or in your component template file (inside the view). Check where jQuery is inserted in the first place. Having jQuery duplicates is also not good.

Comment: Do you have team viewer you can see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the place to add it is exactly after the  tag referencing jQuery. From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: Can i send you the file to check it your self because am not pro in development

Answer (score 0):

Should Google a little bit.

1. [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5015108/1085285)
2. http://uzbekjon.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-use-jQuery_noConflict
3. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/