# TypeError: $(...).colorbox is not a function

Tags: javascript, youtube, lightbox

I am using bellow js code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:390});
        $(".callbacks").colorbox({
        onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
        onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
        onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
        onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
        onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Then this bellow error coming

> TypeError: $(...).colorbox is not a function [Break On This Error]

```
$(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:390});
```

when I click on video link it directly opening in page instead of lightbox effect

Comment: Have you included the plugin?

Comment: jQuert conflict.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188262/jquery-noconflict

Comment: yes included
there is no conflict
only 2 more js files are there
http://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter.js
and 
www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js

Comment: I am also got same error :(

Comment: then waht u did @ LearnPhp ????

Comment: Any jsfiddle for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just about the most stripped down example I can give, combining your code with some sample code from the website (specifically the JS and CSS from this page: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/). Note that /public is where I store external assets in my setup.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/colorbox.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <a class="youtube cboxElement" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VOJyrQa_WR4?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent">Flash / Video (Iframe/Direct Link To YouTube)</a>
    <script src="/public/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:390});
        $(".callbacks").colorbox({
        onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
        onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
        onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
        onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
        onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

That code produces a link which, when clicked, opens a lightboxed video with your size specifications.

Comment: So was the reason it wasn't working because the <a> link was written after the js code was written?