# How to use noConflict and $ in same page

Tags: jquery, html

I want use `noConflict` and `$` in same page

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>hello</h1>
<input type="button" id="=mybtn2" value="jq" onclick="myfun2();" />
<input type="button" id="mybtn" value="$" onclick="myfun();" />
```

```js
var jq = $.noConflict();

function myfun() {
    $("p").text("This is p tag with $");
}

function myfun2() {
    jq("h1").text("his is a header with jq");
}
```

Comment: Read here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-noconflict.htm and you will get your answer

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188262/jquery-noconflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery.noConflict()` is only for using two different versions of jQuery or loading two different libraries using `$`. Good example is:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
    console.log(jq.fn.jquery);      // 1.9.1
    console.log($.fn.jquery);       // 1.11.3
    console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);  // 1.11.3
</script>
```

The usecase I was talking is, some plugins require older versions, say, `1.9.1` and a few require the newer versions. In that case, you can use the `noConflict` to load the old ones and new ones in the same page.

See the better use-case here:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="old-plugin.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".old-plugin-holder").oldPlugin();
    jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="new-plugin.js"></script>
<script>
    console.log(jq.fn.jquery);      // 1.9.1
    console.log($.fn.jquery);       // 1.11.3
    console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);  // 1.11.3

    // Initialization
    jq(".old-plugin-holder").oldPlugin(); // Runs using jQuery 1.9.1
    $(".new-plugin-holder").newPlugin();  // Runs using jQuery 1.11.3
</script>
```