# How to prevent jQuery overlading on my site (e.g. by a browser addon)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery on my website and Honeybadger to get notified about javascript exceptions. The tool shows me many errors that occurr because the global `jQuery` and `$` variables are overwritten by another jQuery-Version (e.g. from https://ajax.googleapis.com/...)

So I am thinking about using `jQuery.noConflict` to use another variable for jQuery (e.g. `$j`). Since I use a few addons for jQuery, this must happen right after all of them are loaded, right?

But does it work all the time or might another jQuery be injected before all my addons are loaded?

Comment: Related questions: [jQuery: noConflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188262/jquery-noconflict) and [How do I implement JQuery.noConflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882374/how-do-i-implement-jquery-noconflict) and [+2000 more...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+noconflict)

Answer (score 0):

As long as all your plugins know to use $j it won't matter when the other jquery is loaded.